# Is the use of 'till' and 'through' equivalent in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, differences

Suppose one would say:

> chapters 1 through 4

That would be equivalent to:

> chapters 1, 2, 3, and 4

Could that statement be rephrased as:

> chapters 1 till 4

Is that a correct statement, and if so, can one always replace through with till to mean 'to and including'?

Comment: Hello, JJJ. Where have you seen this usage? Please add examples with links.

Comment: An example would be: "The first exam will be on Chapter 2 sections 4 till 7, Chapter 3, sections 1 till 3 and
Chapter 4 section 1." in http://www.math.tamu.edu/~grigoris/Math411-Practice-2ndExam-Spring2017.pdf .

Another example: "In sections 1 till 5, the paper discusses successively" in http://www.webmeets.com/files/papers/EAERE/2016/102/paper_submission_EAERE_2016.pdf

I actually found someone writing it in a less formal setting, but was't sure if it was correct. I should add that I found these urls with a Google search, I am not affiliated in any way with these sources.

Comment: "Till" is ambiguous -- it's unclear whether you mean to include chapter 4 or stop at 3.  "Through" makes it clear that you mean to include chapter 4.  Furthermore, "till" (in this sense) is a hair archaic.

Comment: I've searched "sections 1 till" on Google, and the tiny number of relevant  hits suggests that (a) this is a non-standard usage that is (b) largely confined to non-native speakers. Perhaps they are confusing a non-temporal interval (1 through/to 5) with a temporal one (1 till 5).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that was my guess too, most of those results seem to be written by Dutch people. Knowing Dutch myself, I know that in Dutch there is one word for 'up to and including', 'through', and 'till' (in a sense of: until a certain time). So that explains the small number of results. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Hot Licks I can't find a dictionary licensing a usage of 'till' in the 'up to' sense that isn't temporal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/should-you-use-until-or-till-or-til

Comment: I'm with @EdwinAshworth on this one. It's worth stressing that "temporal" subsumes uses like "until you get to", but for the question in hand, it's not really appropriate. I'd just write *Chapters 1–4* and be done with it ...

Comment: @Hot Licks '[T]he earliest [pre 1410] sense of the word was the same as the preposition _to_' hardly justifies 'a hair archaic'. There are no recent examples in the article.

Comment: Btw, the OP is expected to do some background effort by checking out the meaning and usage of each of the alternatives and see what fits the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> chapters 1 through 4

(should be your best bet)

> chapters 1, 2, **3** and 4

(No need for comma after "3")

> chapters 1 **to** 4

("to," not "till" - "to" works fine, although technically "to" is supposed to be ambiguous about whether it includes "4" or not).

*Till* is used only in reference to **time** -- "I waited till 5 pm" may be acceptable.